# How to attach ground wire for ceiling fixture, if mounting bracket does not have a green ground screw, and no ground wire coming from junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My ceiling metal junction box has 2 white wires(twisted together) and 1 black wire. No copper or ground wire inside that I can see?  The new fixture has a black, white and green/yellow ground wire.  The provided new metal mounting strap bracket does not have a green ground screw.
What can I attach the green/yellow ground wire from the fixture to??

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the ceiling box please?

Comment: Given the confusion below, can you elaborate where this installation is located?

Answer (score 1):

Although 2 whites and a black would be unusual.
In the US code allows for a grounding conductor to be pulled from the service, or any point fed from that service panel.

2 wire fixtures did not have grounds for the first 75 years of electrical code so many fixtures were not grounded.

If fed by conduit and individual wires the box may be grounded through the conduit.

Comment: Not every conduit and in some states any conduit approved as ground.

Comment: @user263983 this is true, and some flexible metallic that was used in the past is no longer code, non metallic is not a ground method but that’s fairly obvious.

Comment: In the case of a 2 wire ungrounded system, if updating wiring is not an option, the circuit can be GFCI protected.

Comment: Yes if you add GFCI protection you can install 3 wire receptacles, the receptacles require a sticker stating GFCI protected no equipment ground. Note, in this case the test button will work on the GFCI device but a plug in tester will not trip the device because lack of a equipment ground. This advice is based on the NEC. I should mention not all lighting outlets require a ground since the op is asking about lighting and lighting circuits do not require GFCI, lighting fixtures that don’t have exterior conductive parts do not require a ground.

Answer (score 0):

All metal parts has to be grounded. Check carefully your junction box, bare copper wire should be connected to screw inside the box. You can connect the ground wire from your fixture to same screw or another screw in the box. If you have wiring in your house with ground wire,
the metal box body is ground. If the wire from fixture too short, make a jumper. If it is no ground wire, leave the fixture ground wire not connected or may connect it to box screw. Two white wires connected together because the neutral is jumped from that box to another. Connect white wire from fixture to them. An black to black.

Comment: @jack edited. Some countries only qualified electrician can make a wires changing. Lack of knowledge can be dangerous.

Comment: Yes, lack of knowledge is dangerous which is why we stress safety and  following codes where applicable.

Comment: Correction:  depending on jurisdiction and date installed metal parts may be required to be grounded in the US.  pre1960 grounding was not required (I did not look up the exact year).

Answer (score -6):

<s>I assume that the two white wires are two lives are for two separate circuits (i. e. two lights, switchable seperately or light+ceiling fan) and the black wire is neutral. In this case, you would connect the ground to the neutral. That's the normal way to do this if you have no ground. However, I would first check what the incoming wires actually connect to. Also you can't have an RCD with this kind of wiring because it would blow the RCD immediately if you touch the grounded parts of your new fixture.</s>

Comment: Completely off-base for North American wiring...

Comment: What do you mean off-base? Are you trying to tell me that North America has an ungrounded power grid where the neutral isn't grounded? In that case, you would be right. But an ungrounded grid would be... odd. Very odd.

Comment: Neutral connected to ground only at power source, mainly transformer or main switch.  Color of neutral either white or grey, Europe- blue. Black is live wire, phase.

Comment: General message:  I'm getting troubled by the electrical advice given when we don't know nearly enough to give good advice/answers. IE: What country are you in? If in USA, what state? How old is the structure you are working on? Let's get the complete picture before posting answers. OK?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I agree, like I said in a previous comment, it really depends upon where you are on this planet.  But never heard of a black being considered a neutral anywhere.

Comment: @erebus  I don't mean to be rude, really, and I'm sorry to have to say this,  but if you don't know if "North America has an ungrounded power grid" or not, you are completely unqualified to answer electrical questions. Yes, America has a grounded power grid where the neutral is grounded.  It's been that way for about 120 years.

Comment: Yeah, given the metal box and odd number of wires, OP is certainly in a conduit system.  A metal box all but implies metal conduit, and in North America, metal conduit carries ground for you (the Soviets were into that too).  In these installations you don't see apparent ground *wires*. But even in your country, **neutral is not ground** and you do not use them for each other.  Yes, I am well aware that you have seen neutral and ground connected to each other somewhere in your system.  The crux is the "somewhere".

Comment: I know very well that over here in Europe, black is live. However, I was assuming North America could be doing this differently. Now we established that black is neutral, why are there two neutrals in this wire???

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Over here in Germany, you sometimes come across legacy installations that lack a ground wire. Now how do you connect a mains outlet in this case? The correct way to do this is to use the neutral for ground. In German, this way of wiring an outlet is called “klassische Nullung“ and it is standard procedure if you want to retrofit an old installation with normal grounded outlets. Not sure what the term translates to in English.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The metal conduit carries the ground and there is no ground wire? I've never heard or seen this before. Here in Germany, junction boxes are never metal. Now that you've introduced me to metal conduits, please accept my introduction to the bootleg ground.

Comment: Btw, bootleg ground was banned in the US in 1996 and in Germany in 1974 for **new** installations.

Comment: A more modern way to accomodate old 2 wire circuits when a ground can't be added is to GFCI protect them.  The bootleg ground existed at some point in Canada as well as 2 wire systems with metal parts and no ground, and we have the option of using EMT as ground as well as a wide variety of plastic and metal boxes whether running NMD or EMT.  I've always thought you'd have to be incredibly cheap to forego pulling a ground wire even with properly installed EMT though.  I've found hundreds of missed set screws, lock nuts and compression nuts over the years.

Comment: @KH huh? Are you seriously proposing to use an RCD as a replacement for grounding? I may not be qualified to judge what you're doing on your side of the pond but over here, even with an RCD you would still need grounding because ground is compulsory these days. Now if your only option to get grounding is a bootleg ground, you can't have an RCD because the RCD would blow very quickly as soon as you touch something that is grounded. So you can't have an RCD if you don't have state-of-the-art grounding.

Comment: @Erebus over here systems originally run without grounds still exist.  If you open up walls or pull a permit to rewire an area, everything must be brought up to code, but just changing devices does not require this.  If a circuit is not to be brought up to the new standard, we GFCI protect it.  Given that the usual reason someone doesn't gut their entire house to add grounds as soon as they find it's ungrounded is that many people absolutely can't afford it without saving and planning, it's really not a bad solution.  Even in a wood frame house it's not too bad to trip one.

Comment: It requires the same wire and is far superior to the bootleg ground.